Why is my main thread immediately stopping and exiting?
I'm implementing two-sided conversation transcription using Python Flask and React.js.
I'm getting audio streams from microphone and speaker using the Python SoundCard library.
I'm transcribing from these audio streams using Azure Conversation Transcriber.
I'm sending the transcript from my Flask backend to the React frontend using Websockets.
Attaching minimal code:



Using npm start for the React frontend and running the python script all works fine.
Once I press the start button, the 'start_recording' request is sent from frontend to backend and properly received. However, the program immediately exits without printing any error message.
If I uncomment the time.sleep(100), the program runs as expected. I don't want to use time.sleep() like this though because I don't know how long the call will be and I don't want to halt the thread.
Any ideas?
Thanks in advance..

Maybe first use print() (and print(type(...)), print(len(...)), etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called "print debugging" and it helps to see what code is really doing.

did you run code in terminal to see error message? As for me you should get error because you start thread in wrong way. threads.append( Thread() ).start() but it should be t = Thread() t.start() threads.append(t)

threads start in background but rest of code doesn't wait for its end. It needs some code which works all time - while True: ....test if it end of data ... - or at least it needs t.join() to wait for end of thread.

it seems start_recognition runs start_transcribing_async() which may suggests that it run async function and it also doesn't wait for the end of data. So it seems all your code run in "background" and now it is your task to keep it running - if you will not do this then it will end start_recording().

Thanks for your response.
I incorrectly wrote my code here. The threads are started properly. I chose to forget about the array for now and just made the thread and started on same line correctly without any error in terminal.
My confusion is about the flask server. I am starting the flask server and then it immediately turns off after creating all these threads and everything. In fact, the "started" is correctly returned too.
When I don't click the start button, no threads are started but the flask server stays running. Then why does it stop running all of a sudden after these threads?

Like you are saying I need some code to always be running or it will reach end of execution. But when there are no threads created, it continues to run even though there is no code being executed. But when the code in start_recording is executed, now I need something to keep the program running? Are you understanding where I am finding inconsistency/confusion?

And when I do put in that time.sleep(), everything works (of course, until the sleep is over). That means everything else in the code is working correctly adding to audio queue and transcribing from audio queue, right?

I have no idea how this code works. I may only suggest to use print() (and print(type(...)), print(len(...)), etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called "print debugging" and it helps to see what code is really doing.

if code works when you have sleep then it are missing code which will run all time - similar to sleep but longer. Like endless loop while True: asyncio.sleep(1)
